# select all checkboxes of a form

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, will-paginate

In my rails application, i am displaying some records. I am using pagination for records..
i have a javascript function to select all the checkboxes associated with a record..But it selects checkboxes of only current page. I want to have a feature where i can select all the checboxes of current page and then move to next page selec there and then submit all of them together.

Answer (score 3):

I'd say hopping between pages and selecting everything is way too tedious and extremely error prone.

Have your "Check all" function submit something like a `yourform[check_all]=true` parameter to your controller (via ajax or plain HTTP POST) and have your controller handle the requested action on all relevant records.

Comment: Yup my check all method will check for all the checkboxes in that form and checks every checkboxes.. In controller i have then all the values of checkboxes checked and by this i can fetch the record for all the checked values.. Now i want a functionality where i can check all the records on this page and then move to nxt page without submitting my form and then again check all the checkboxes of other pages and finally submit all the checked one all together.

Comment: Do you want to select **some** records (not **all** records) on the next page?

Comment: It depends.. it should work for one record selected as well as all selected.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I have done the same task as you. I am using table with Ajax pagination, so I can remember all checked positions in array or other object. Then I've added on-click handler to submit button where hidden fields are adding to form to make the same effect as missing checkboxes.